# How to create matrix of all 2^n binary sequences of length n using recursion in R?

Tags: r, recursion, combinatorics, binary-data

I know I can use `expand.grid` for this, but I am trying to learn actual programming. My goal is to take what I have below and use a recursion to get all 2^n binary sequences of length n.

I can do this for n = 1, but I don't understand how I would use the same function in a recursive way to get the answer for higher dimensions.

Here is for n = 1:

```
binseq <- function(n){
  binmat <- matrix(nrow = 2^n, ncol = n)
  r <- 0 #row counter
  for (i in 0:1) {
        r <- r + 1
        binmat[r,] <- i
    }
  return(binmat)
  }
```

I know I have to use probably a `cbind` in the return statement. My intuition says the return statement should be something like `cbind(binseq(n-1), binseq(n))`. But, honestly, I'm completely lost at this point.

The desired output should produce something like what expand.grid gives:

```
n = 5
expand.grid(replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
```

It should just be a matrix as binmat is being filled recursively.

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? By the way, this is simply combinations with repetition and if you want probably the best representation of recursion in R, look no further than `gtools::combinations`. Just type it in the console and scroll down to the block where repetition is allowed. You will also see that your intuition is on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in a comment (below), **here is a limited implementation for binary sequences only:**

```
eg.binary <- function(n, digits=0:1) {
  if (n <= 0) return(matrix(0,0,0))
  if (n == 1) return(matrix(digits, 2))
  x <- eg.binary(n-1)
  rbind(cbind(digits[1], x), cbind(digits[2], x))
}
```

After taking care of an initial case that `R` cannot handle correctly, it treats the "base case" of n=1 and then recursively obtains all n-1-digit binary strings and prepends each digit to each of them.  The digits are prepended so that the binary strings end up in their usual lexicographic order (the same as `expand.grid`).

Example:

> ```
> eg.binary(3)
> ```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0
[4,]    0    1    1
[5,]    1    0    0
[6,]    1    0    1
[7,]    1    1    0
[8,]    1    1    1
```

A general explanation (with a more flexible solution) follows.

---

Distill the problem down to the basic operation of tacking the values of an array `y` onto the rows of a dataframe `X`, associating a whole copy of `X` with each value (*via* `cbind`) and appending the whole lot (*via* `rbind`):

```
cross <- function(X, y) {
  do.call("rbind", lapply(y, function(z) cbind(X, z)))
}
```

For example,

> ```
> cross(data.frame(A=1:2, b=letters[1:2]), c("X","Y"))
> ```

```
  A b z
1 1 a X
2 2 b X
3 1 a Y
4 2 b Y
```

(Let's worry about the column names later.)

The recursive solution for a list of such arrays `y` assumes you have already carried out these operations for all but the last element of the list.  It has to start somewhere, which evidently consists of converting an array into a one-column data frame.  Thus:

```
  eg_ <- function(y) {
    n <- length(y)
    if (n <= 1) {
      as.data.frame(y) 
    } else {
      cross(eg_(y[-n]), y[[n]])
    }
  }
```

---

Why the funny name?  Because we might want to do some post-processing, such as giving the result nice names.  Here's a fuller implementation:

```
eg <- function(y) {
  # (Define `eg_` here to keep it local to `eg` if you like)
  X <- eg_(y)
  names.default <- paste0("Var", seq.int(length(y)))
  if (is.null(names(y))) {
    colnames(X) <- names.default
  } else {
    colnames(X) <- ifelse(names(y)=="", names.default, names(y))
  }
  X
}
```

For example:

> ```
> eg(replicate(3, 0:1, simplify=FALSE))
> ```

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    0    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    0
4    1    1    0
5    0    0    1
6    1    0    1
7    0    1    1
8    1    1    1
```

> ```
> eg(list(0:1, B=2:3))
> ```

```
  Var1 B
1    0 2
2    1 2
3    0 3
4    1 3
```

Comment: I see by your example this works inasmuch as it returns the desired output, more or less. However, sadly, this is well beyond where I'm at. There are several things going on here that I don't understand but will give more time. That said, I was looking for something simpler that would return all 2^n possible binary combinations (in a matrix) with a recursive function for just one input n = ?. Basically, it doesn't have to be so versatile.

Comment: I coded it like this specifically because you stated you wanted to emulate `expand.grid`.

Comment: Yeah, i realized that was a mistake :( I was just using that as a very quick way of generating the desired output. I'm going to look over your code though and see what i can learn from it. I did manage a solution after asking a former professor for help. The book I got the problem from was a tad misleading in how they wanted you to solve it.

Comment: I also want to understand the general algorithm better. 

So when you use the cross function, the third argument is actually z in the function(z) within the cross function? I've never done anything as advanced yet as using functions within functions in this particular way.

So it seems like function(z) cbinds x and z and then y for all elements of y. So if y has 2 elements you will have two cbinds of x and z that will be identical but the larger yxz matric will have rows unique to the elements of y? but then where does rbind come in? What are you rbinding? Looks like rbind has 1 argument.

Comment: Indeed, `rbind` does have one argument: it's a *list* of objects to concatenate.  See the help for `rbind` for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was the desired recursive code:

```
binseq <- function(n){
  if(n == 1){
    binmat <- matrix(c(0,1), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
  }else if(n > 1){
    A <- binseq(n-1)
    B <- cbind(rep(0, nrow(A)), A)
    C <- cbind(rep(1, nrow(A)), A)
    binmat <- rbind(B,C)
  }
  return(binmat)
  }
```

Basically for n = 1 we create a [0, 1] matrix. For every n there after we add a column of 0's to the original matrix, and, separately, a column of 1's. Then we rbind the two matrices to get the final product. So I get what the algorithm is doing, but I don't really understand what the recursion is doing. For example, I don't understand the step from n = 2 to n = 3 based on the algorithm.

Comment: I see this is basically identical to what you did in the limited interpretation. Could you help explain exactly what the recursive step is doing? How is it generating the bigger and bigger matrix you bind digits to for larger n based on the first step for n = 1? I don't understand that because it seems those would have to have a separate bind command?